# What does "erst" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "erst" mean in this context?

> Möchten Sie gleich zahlen oder erst später?

Is it necessary to use "erst" in this sentence while I think "später" single-handedly makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences

> Möchten Sie gleich zahlen oder erst später?

and

> Möchten Sie gleich zahlen oder später?

carry the same primary meaning and are well-formed.

However, the *erst* adds some information about how the speaker relates to the situation: using *erst* in this situation, the speaker emphasises that he leaves it completely open to his counterpart to decide when to pay. You can see this as a form of being polite and friendly. Without the *erst*, the utterance may seem a little bit rough or demanding. Of course, it depends also on the tone.

Comment: My _Sprachgefühl_ tells me that _erst_ only indicates that the action will happen later, basically affirming the information given by _später_. Such pleonasms are not unusual in German. Compare with _schon früher_ vs _früher_.

Comment: Ich sehe es umgekehrt. "gleich oder später" ist völlig neutral. "Erst später" sagt, dass das auch möglich ist, aber üblich ist, oder der Fragende wünscht eher gleich. Um das Gegenteil auszudrücken würde man fragen "schon gleich zahlen oder später".

Answer (score 3):

Adding the *»erst«* is a mild method to indicate that one would prefer to get the money at once. Without the *»erst«* both possibilities would be equivalent.

Comment: Interestingly this is **exactly the opposite** of what I feel it says (see my actual answer). I cannot imagine a situation where 'erst' would add urgency to the meanting of that specific sentence. - As I would not dare to question your experience, should we then have to suppose that these sentences are received differently in different parts of the German speaking world?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Im Beispielsatz kennzeichnet der Sprecher mittels _»erst«_ die für ihn schlechtere Alternative. Ich glaube, das funktioniert deshalb, weil _»erst«_ im deutschen Sprachgebrauch häufiger verwendet wird, um etwas Schlechtes oder Schlechteres zu beschreiben als etwas Gutes. Beispiele: _»Er wollte um fünf kommen, kam aber erst um sechs.«_ (Warten!) _»Der Bus/Das Essen kam erst nach eineinhalb Stunden.«_ (Warten!) _»Erst nach zwei Stunden der Erklärung hat mein Sohn mich verstanden.«_ (Aufwand!) _»Erst die Arbeit, dann das Vergnügen.«_ (Plage!)

Comment: Im letzten Beispiel ist die Bedeutung von *erst* anders als zuvor. Hier bedeutet es ja gerade nicht, dass etwas später geschieht, sondern früher. Es ist eine Verkürzung von *zuerst*.

Comment: @Christiangeiselmann Ich würde dieser Antwort zustimmen. Ohne Zusatz von *erst* wäre es gleichwertig. Durch den Zusatz *erst* wird die Abweichung von der als normal erwarteten Variante deutlich gemacht. Genauso könnte man die andere Variante mit *schon* ergänzen, wenn man normalerweise von der späteren Zahlung ausgehen würde und die sofortige Zahlung eher unerwartet wäre.

Comment: @Pollitzer. Ja, das ist technisch gesehen schon richtig. Jedoch ist die Herleitung einer Satzbedeutung allein aus den semantischen Bestandteilen nicht immer ausreichend. Es kommt auch auf die Pragmatik an. Anders gesagt: Wie werden solche Sätze in Alltagssituationen konkret verwendet? Und hier treten, wie wir sehen, mindestens zwei Varianten auf: Man fügt *erst* hinzu, um die schlechtere Option zu kennzeichnen (Deine Lesart), oder man fügt 'erst' hinzu, um höflicher zu sein (meine Lesart). Mögliche Herleitung meiner Lesart: Wortreichere Äußerungen gelten in der Regel als höflicher.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Meiner Ansicht nach wird der Satz durch das Einfügen von _»erst«_ unhöflicher, da er die Freiheit des Kunden durch ein Lenkenwollen angreift. Die bloße Zahl der Worte hilft da nicht wirklich weiter.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Ja, das haben wir ja schon festgestellt: Du empfindest den Effekt des Hinzufügens von *erst* ziemlich genau andersherum als ich. Ich habe, da mich die Sache interessierte, ein bisschen herumgefragt, und ich finde Leute, die deine Meinung teilen, Leute, die meine Meinung teilen, und Leute, die sagen, dass sie überhaupt keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen empfinden.

Comment: Ich finde, die Bedeutung des Satzes hängt vom Gesichtsausdruck des Sprechers und vom restlichen Kontext ab. Das "erst" kann einerseits als Ungeduld gedeutet werden, andererseits kann es genauso gut Gelassenheit ausdrücken, ja sogar eine Gleichgültigkeit. Können wir uns denn darauf einigen, dass die Wirkung des "erst" auf jeden Fall sehr gering ist?

Comment: @Roland Illig: Eine Wirkung haben wir dann, wenn der subtile Versuch der Gängelung beim Kunden tatsächlich zu einer sofortigen Zahlung führt, entgegen seiner ursprünglichen Absicht. Wie oft das passiert, kann ich nicht sagen.

Answer (score 0):

In this context you could translate "erst später" as "wait until later".

"Möchten Sie gleich zahlen oder später?" -> "Do you want to pay now or later?"

"Möchten Sie gleich zahlen oder erst später?" -> Do you want to pay now or wait until later?"

Putting "erst" in makes it seem a little more polite, but I don't see a difference in meaning.